# How to handle null DateTimes in .NET and convert them to specified DateTime?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

In the last line, it will give an error "Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime." when dr.item("t$ltdt") is equal to null.

How can I handle null DateTimes and convert them into specified DateTime?

```
Dim sqlCur As String = "SELECT * FROM baan.ttiitm001800  WHERE (t$kitm ='1' or t$kitm='4') " & ItemCondtion & "  ORDER BY t$item"

    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(sqlCur, connBaan)
    Dim dr As OracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

    If dr.HasRows Then
        While dr.Read()
            Dim ChkItmCd As String = "SELECT Item_Code FROM MPC_Item_Master WHERE Item_Code='" & Trim(dr.Item("t$item")) & "' "
            db.OpenTable(ChkItmCd)

            If db.Eof Then
                ItmType = Trim(dr.Item("t$kitm"))   

                If (Trim(dr.Item("t$kitm")) = "1") Then
                    ItmType = "PURCHASED"
                ElseIf (Trim(dr.Item("t$kitm")) = "4") Then
                    ItmType = "COST"
                End If

                Dim ltdt As Date = dr.Item("t$ltdt")
```

Comment: if they are null the field wont convert to a DateTime because there is no point in time which is null.  Perhaps you could clarify

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the [Convert.ToDateTime method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It takes in a large variety of formats and converts it to a DateTime.

Also, make sure your input is not null:

```
Dim ltdt As Date
If dr.Item("t$ltdt") IsNot Nothing Then
    ltdt = Convert.ToDateTime(dr.Item("t$ltdt"))
End If
```